# Only show command in context menu on specific filename (+extension)

Tags: visual-studio, contextmenu, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-2019

So basically I only want to display the Command when I right click on a file named "example.cs". Since I am using Visual Studio 2019 I can't go with the old `BeforeQueryStatus` way. Instead using the `ProvideUIContextRule` Attribute on my Package class. Which currently looks something like this:

```
    [ProvideUIContextRule(_uiContextSupportedFiles,
    name: "Supported Files",
    expression: "CSharp",
    termNames: new[] { "CSharp" },
    termValues: new[] { "HierSingleSelectionName:.cs$" })]
```

Which totally looks fine for the extension of the file itself. So is there any way to restrict it to `example.cs`?

By the way I am using this [Guide](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/VisibilityConstraints#lets-get-started).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for everyone else having the same issue as I had. The solution is fairly simple, regarding to the MSDN:

> (...) The term evaluates to true whenever the current selection in the active hierarchy has a name that matches the regular expression pattern(...)

So basically changing
`{ "HierSingleSelectionName:.cs$" }` to `{ "HierSingleSelectionName:Program.cs$" }` will only show files that end with `Program.cs`.

This leads to, that everything after the semicolon contains a Regular Expression.

Comment: Hi Twenty, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT just letting you know, there is a 6 hour cooldown before you can accept your own answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

To determine your command's visibility, you can implement QueryStatus method.

Implement `Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget` like CommandsFilter. And add it as service to package.

```
var serviceContainer = (IServiceContainer)this; // this - is your Package/AsyncPakage
var commandTargetType = typeof(IOleCommandTarget);
var commandsFilter = new CommandsFilter();
serviceContainer.RemoveService(commandTargetType);
serviceContainer.AddService(commandTargetType, commandsFilter);
```

On every commands update will be called method `QueryStatus` in CommandsFilter.
Wait for your command id and change it status

```
class CommandsFilter : IOleCommandTarget {
// ...
public int QueryStatus(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText) {
    var cmdId = prgCmds[0].cmdID;
    // check cmdId and set status depends on your conditions
    // like fileName == "example.cs"
    prgCmds[0].cmdf = (uint)GetVsStatus(status);

    //....
}

private OLECMDF GetVsStatus(CommandStatus commandStatus) {

  OLECMDF ret = 0;
  if (commandStatus.HasFlag(CommandStatus.Supported))
    ret |= OLECMDF.OLECMDF_SUPPORTED;
  if (commandStatus.HasFlag(CommandStatus.Enabled))
    ret |= OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED;
  if (commandStatus.HasFlag(CommandStatus.Invisible))
    ret |= OLECMDF.OLECMDF_INVISIBLE;
  return ret;
}
```

Check [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/blob/c6b80a4ff7023578649d7edecc8fd6cd8a34da10/Backwards_Compatible_Editor_Command/src/LegacyCommandHookup/CommandFilter.cs) with `QueryStatus` and others MS samples

Comment: You should copy paste the relevant portions instead of just putting a link that can go away

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @vik_78 So I have a few questions to this, how do I determine my commandId and how would I get more information about the item clicked.